# Unable to use extensions within class-files

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, I'm simply unable to actually use the extensions API's in class-files through Visual Studio. I'm trying to add the using-statements, but it's just not working. My Visual Studio won't even recognize it.

The extensions for some reason work just fine in Views, just not in class-files.

I hope you can help me!

An example could be the popular Umbraco extension called ArcheType.
In a class file I would do the following at the top:

```
using ArcheType.Models;
```

But Visual Studio marks the using-statement as an error. But as I said, if I use the exact same using-statement in a View, that works completely fine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please provide code sample, what extensions don't work ?

Comment: My bad, sorry. It has been added to the question.

Comment: did you add the extension to your project reference ?

Comment: Have you referenced project which defines `ArcheType.Models` class ?

Comment: Yes to both of you, if I didn't, I wouldn't be able to use it in my Views I would assume. Regardless, it is in my project's references as "Archetype.dll".

Comment: So what's the error you got?

Comment: "The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" That's all.

Comment: Any more details in the 'warnings' section?

Comment: Nope, I'm not getting any warnings.

Comment: Strange. My first guess would be a .Net framework version mismatch (the referenced dll targeting a higher version), but you'd normally get a warning about that as well.

Comment: Yeah I find it extremely strange as well and I really can't figure out what the issue is. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Oh and by the way, it's not just for one DLL, this happens for all Umbraco extensions more or less. There's a few of them I am able to use in class files, but the others I can only use in Views.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions I was unable to use in my class files through Visual Studio were installed through Umbraco's Package Installer. After installing them through NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, they work completely fine with a "using directive".

So I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: Ah, yes, they need to be referenced in your project for you to be able to use them in code behind. Your views just look in the bin folder for the file (and it's there because you installed via Umbraco). You COULD also just add a reference to the file inside VS, instead of using NuGet (but NuGet is recommended :-) ).

Comment: Ah, I see. I just assumed they were referenced because I included them in the project, but yeah. Thanks :p